# Боковое меню с выбором языка

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

при написании приложения использую Navigation Drawer Activity. Интересует можно-ли каким-то образом при выборе одного из элементов бокового меню вызывать всплывающее модальное окно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим при нажатии кнопки язык, чтобы всплывало модальное окно с предложением выбрать язык как при использовании ListPreference.

Comment: конечно можно) Ставите обработчик на нажатие в меню, и по клику создаете модульное диалоговое окно (можно прикрутить готовую либу на это дело)

Comment: Не подскажете какую?

Comment: поищите тут)) https://android-arsenal.com/tag/138?sort=created

Comment: Добавлю свои 5 копеек, но это не самое правильное построение UI, обычно дравер подразумевает то, что по нажатию на элемент он скроется и пользователь увидит страницу. Если бы я встретил такое в приложении, то у меня бы начало бомбить, без шуток) Ноооо, это вопросы UX

Comment: поддерживаю. Полагаю, правильнее было-бы реализовать выбор языка в отдельном окне (либо поместить выбора языка во фрагмент с настройками, а уже внутри по необходимости вызывать модальное окно\)